# How to remove border when WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency=“False” and ResizeMode="CanResize"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have a window with the following properties

```
WindowState="Maximized"
WindowStyle="None, 
AllowsTransparency="False"
ResizeMode="CanResize"
```

But the problem is a border appears around the window.
How can I fix it without changing any of these properties

When I set AllowsTransparency True some user controls such as PdfViewer,WebBrowser not displaying contents.

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        AllowsTransparency="False"
        ResizeMode="CanResize"
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid Background="Red"></Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`WindowChrome`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=netframework-4.8):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="False"
        ResizeMode="CanResize"
        UseLayoutRounding="True"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="0" ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Grid Background="Red"></Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It worked but still some user controls such as PdfViewer,WebBrowser not displaying contents.

Comment: The built-in `WebBrowser` control clearly works as expected. Try to replace the `Grid` with a `<WebBrowser Source="http://google.com" />`. I don't what `PdfViewer` is, but if this control doesn't work as expected it's a separate issue