# How to remove the white border appearing over the top of the window

Tags: c#, wpf

A white border is showing up at the top when the following properties are set :
ResizeMode : CanResize
AllowTransparency : false
WindowStyle : None

I wanted to have the popup(window) a border with shadow.

If I set the resize mode to NoResize Or I change the allowTransparency to true the border disappears.

The code is in c#.

[image: White border popup/window]

Is there any property similar to CaptionHeight (WindowChrome). [image: Window with no border]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58303198/3137337